# Как в C++ вывести данные таблицей?

Tags: c++

есть файл, в нём содержатся элементы структуры

```
struct book 
{
string title;
string authors;
string publisher;
int year;
unsigned int pages;
};
```

Каким образом можно на c++ без использования printf, вывести данные из файла таблицей, чтобы получилось нечто:

```
title authors publisher ....... ....   ... 
A       Z.N    RUSSIA
B       V.F     CHINA
```

И т.д

Пытался сделать с setw,но после заполнения заголовков(title.authors ...) не понимал как правильно вывести остальное